# node.js to insert into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a simple program that stores a list of crimes into a mongodb database, however I've tried many solutions for the last few hours and it seems like Node.js only sees one data and it's undefined!  Yes the file interventionscitoyendo.csv is not empty and is located right next to the javascript file.  Any ideas?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('interventionscitoyendo.csv');
var http = require('http');
var iclite = require("iconv-lite");
var csv = require('csv');
var object = csv();
var db = null;
var request = http.get("http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/5829b5b0-ea6f-476f-be94-bc2b8797769a/resource/c6f482bf-bf0f-4960-8b2f-9982c211addd/download/interventionscitoyendo.csv", function(response) {
response.pipe(file);
});

//Create Data-Base
var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

mongo.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, database) {
if (err){ console.log(err);}
db = database;
var dbo = db.db("Crimes");
var ListeCrimes = [];
object.from.path('interventionscitoyendo.csv').to.array(function (data) {
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
  var crime = {
    CATEGORIE: iclite.decode(data[index][0], "ISO-8859-1"),
    DATE: data[index][1],
    QUART: data[index][2],
    PDQ: data[index][3],
    X: data[index][4],
    Y: data[index][5],
    LATITUDE: data[index][6],
    LONGITUDE: data[index][7]
  };
  console.log(crime);
  ListeCrimes.push(crime);
}
console.log(data.length);
dbo.collection("Crimes").insertMany(ListeCrimes, function(err, res) {
    if (err){ console.log(err);}
    else { console.log("A1 works"); }
});
if (data.status == 200){
  db.close();
}
});
});
```

And the output is :

```
{ CATEGORIE: '',
DATE: undefined,
QUART: undefined,
PDQ: undefined,
X: undefined,
Y: undefined,
LATITUDE: undefined,
LONGITUDE: undefined }
1
A1 works
```

Comment: Where are you piping your readable stream to a writable stream? `response.pipe(file);` needs to pipe to a write stream

Comment: that part doesn't seem to be the problem, because I can see the data in the csv file, it's when I try to read the csv and put the data into mongodb that causes problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'file' is not completely written, and it starts being read because there is no data. You should wait for *finish* event to raise.

```
file.on('finish', function() {
});
```

In this *finish* event handler, close the file using the async method: file.close.
When the file is closed, you can read and insert in mongo db.

```
file.on('finish', function() {
    file.close(function() {
        // Insert in mongoDB here
    });
});
```

After waiting for files to finish piping, the solution should be the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.createWriteStream('interventionscitoyendo.csv');
var http = require('http');
var iclite = require("iconv-lite");
var csv = require('csv');
var object = csv();
var db = null;
var request = http.get("http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/5829b5b0-ea6f-476f-be94-bc2b8797769a/resource/c6f482bf-bf0f-4960-8b2f-9982c211addd/download/interventionscitoyendo.csv", function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
});

file.on('finish', function() {
    file.close(function() {
      // Create Data-Base
      var mongo = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
      var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

      mongo.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, database) {
          if (err){ console.log(err);}
          db = database;
          var dbo = db.db("Crimes");
          var ListeCrimes = [];
          object.from.path('./interventionscitoyendo.csv').to.array(function (data) {
              for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                  var crime = {
                      CATEGORIE: iclite.decode(data[index][0], "ISO-8859-1"),
                      DATE: data[index][1],
                      QUART: data[index][2],
                      PDQ: data[index][3],
                      X: data[index][4],
                      Y: data[index][5],
                      LATITUDE: data[index][6],
                      LONGITUDE: data[index][7]
                  };
                  console.log(crime);
                  ListeCrimes.push(crime);
              }
              console.log(data.length);
              dbo.collection("Crimes").insertMany(ListeCrimes, function(err, res) {
                  if (err){ console.log(err);}
                  else { console.log("A1 works"); }
              });
              if (data.status == 200){
                  db.close();
              }
          });
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Omg! thanks you solved it! it works!  how and where can I see the data in mongodb just to be sure?

Comment: Since you are inserting all the documents together so you have to wait for program to finish. Once program finishes then go to mongo shell by typing `mongo` and then use Crimes db by using the command `use Crimes`. Since the name of collection is also Crimes so you can use `db.Crimes.Crimes.find()` to check inserted documents.